# Silent MSI Popup

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, altiris

I am running a silent install of an msi driver install, at the end it has a popup that requires the user to hit "OK". I am unable to see this during silent mode or passive mode, is there a way in powershell that I can execute this and force it to pass-through? Anyway to hit "ok" to this without showing the user it is running will be the best option.

Comment: Assuming you are dealing with unsigned driver, the solution is to extract the self signed certificate from your catalog file of the driver, then import the certificate into your trusted root immediately before installing (unsure if reboot required, you'll have to test). Your aclient.exe service should be able to do this, but you would need to mod the script from the deployment console.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell simply invokes the installation process. The Windows Installer service is responsible for interpreting the MSI file and handling installation correctly. If Windows Installer is preventing the window from being displayed, then PowerShell won't be able to see it either.

Comment: Is there  anyway to script that button to get hit, i am using altiris 6.9 as a deployment solution.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're calling `msiexec.exe` correctly:

```
msiexec /i <path to MSI> /q /l*v "$env:TEMP\install.log"
```

That runs it quietly (use `/qb` for just a simple, passive dialog-based install). If it still pops up a dialog, you need to contact the owner of the MSI package and have them fix it. They're breaking the Windows Installer guidelines and there's really no good workaround for it.